# Get table value html

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a mySQL table after a button click..The button click is not the problem but I wonder how I can get the klant_pk which is unique to update a certain record in mySQL. As you see I print out the mySql table at first. So is there anyone who know how I can get the according klant_pk after I click on a button in the table..

Thanks

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM bestelling");
    echo "Bestellingen";
    echo "<table border='1' align='center'>
    <tr>
    <th>Bestelling_pk</th>
    <th>Klant_pk</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Commentaar</th>
    <th>Tijd</th>
    <th> Voortgang </th>
    <th> Status </th>


    </tr>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['bestelling_pk'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['klant_pk'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['opmerking'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['tijd'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td> <input type='button' value='In Wacht' onclick='return change(this);' />";
            echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";       
        }

        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: you need to provide more information. i don't know what you are trying to achieve. for example i have no idea what your `onclick`-javascript does. will it make an `AJAX` call? if you are new to web-developing, maybe try to achieve your goal first by using a simple `<form>` -submission and `POST` the submitted values to another `PHP` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
...
echo "<td id='klank_pk_".$row['klant_pk']."'>" . $row['klant_pk'] . "</td>";
...
echo "<td> <input type='button' value='In Wacht' onclick='change(getElementById('klank_pk_".$row['klant_pk']."').value);' />";
...
}
```

Comment: I think this will help me :) Thanks!